# Google Play installed on Genymotion fails to start

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, adb, genymotion

Genymotion 2.0 has no Google Play as several people have reported here.

- I have Genymotion 2.0 running with ADB.  Running as a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3.
- I have tried to install and run Google Play 4.5.10 and 4.4.22. Genymotion allows drag and drop of APKs to install.
- In both cases Google Play installs, I can see it in settings-apps, it is listed as an app, but when I attempt to run it - an app appears to start (white flash) then immediately stops.
- Can anyone help me past this?

The reasons for this question and the reasons for not using other answered questions is because I do not want to install a new device (the ZEEZOnline solution), and I do not simply need a new account configured (another common response when Google Play *is* running)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Genymotion no longer comes with **Google Apps**, which is a lot more than just the Play store.

But the good news is you can install the full Google Apps package!

Follow [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/11/android-x86-emulator-genymotion-20.html) link, which will point you to the [full Google Apps package](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2), which you can install in genymotion by dragging and dropping.